# HttpResponse vs. Render

Tags: django, http

I was looking over some code and came to this question -- [Django: What is the difference b/w HttpResponse vs HttpResponseRedirect vs render_to_response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921523/django-what-is-the-difference-b-w-httpresponse-vs-httpresponseredirect-vs-render) -- which discusses the different types of request responses.

Is there ever a reason to use `HttpResponse` over `render`? If so, what would be the use case and advantage of doing so? Thank you.

Comment: Abid covers it, `render` is usually used to load a template and a context, while `HttpResponse` is usually for data. As it's bad practice to "respond" with html.  Render is essentially a shortuct for `HttpResponse`, It provides a more effective way to modify templates, and load data dynamically.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`render` is used to for what the name already indicates: to render a template file (mostly HTML, but could be any format). `render` is basically a simple wrapper around a `HttpResponse` which renders a template, though as said in the previous answer, you can use `HttpResponse` to return other things as well in the response, not just rendering templates.

Comment: i hope if you could explain little bit more, that will be awesome.

Comment: Hm, the answer mostly says it already. Django is using templates (template files, e.g. html templates). The `render` shortcut will take a template name as an argument, and then render this template with the given parameters and then return an `HttpResponse` with the rendered body. `HttpResponse` instead does just what the name indicates, dealing with HTTP responses. It does not do the stuff Django does behind the scenes when calling render and in case you want to return a rendered Django template you would need to do this manually and pass that result to the `HttpResponse` before returning.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, say you're making an AJAX call and want to return a JSON object:

```
return HttpResponse(jsonObj, mimetype='application/json')
```

The accepted answer in the original question alluded to this method.

Answer (score 2):

This is arguments for render. It takes the template(template_name) and combines with a given context dictionary and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text.

```
render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
```

Even render return HttpResponse but it can render the template with the context(If a value in the dictionary is callable, the view will call it just before rendering the template.)

```
#With render
def view_page(request):
    # View code here...
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', {
        'value': 'data',
    }, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')

#with HttpResponse
def view_page(request):
    # View code here...
    t = loader.get_template('app/index.html')
    c = {'value': 'data'}
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c, request), content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

In below HttpResponse first we load the template and then render it with context and send the response. So it is quite easy with render because it takes arguments as template_name and context and combines them internally. render is imported by django.shortcuts