# Django: How to return an attribute inside an HttpResponse with meta tags?

Tags: python, django

I have this `return render(...)` for the `simple_upload` view:

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'simple_upload.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        })
    return render(request, 'simple_upload.html')
```

I would like to return something similar in the view `complex_upload` and be able to get the attribute `'uploaded_file_url'` from `complex_upload.html` in the same way as I do with `simple_upload.html` but I don't know how to do it.

Complex upload view:

```
def complex_upload(request, filename):
    import os
    from mimetypes import MimeTypes
    content_type, encoding = MimeTypes().guess_type(
        os.path.basename(filename)
    )
    if content_type is None or len(content_type) == 0:
        print(f'No content-type found for file: {filename}')
        content_type = 'text/plain'
    try:
        url = os.path.join(
            settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(filename)
        )
        with open(url.encode('utf-8'), 'rb') as f:
            uploaded_file_url = f.url(filename)
            resp = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type=content_type)
            resp['X-Robots-Tag'] = 'noindex, nofollow'
            return resp
    except IOError as ex:
        data = {'ERROR': str(ex)}
        print(data)
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Is it possible to combine in a return a render with an attribute and a HttpResponse?

What would be the proper way to do it?

[This question partially solves my doubts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301985/httpresponse-vs-render) but it is not clear to me how to do something like that having meta tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resp is a dictionary
You can simply include the data you want into this dictionary and then return it via HttpResponse.

resp[''uploaded_file_url"] = uploaded_file_url