# Django HttpResponseRedirect vs render_to_response - how to get a login form to behave the way I need it to

Tags: python, django, django-views, httpresponse, django-urls

I've already checked out the following [stackoverflow question regarding the difference between HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, and render_to_response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921523/django-what-is-the-difference-b-w-httpresponse-vs-httpresponseredirect-vs-rende), as well as having gone through the official django docs, but I'm really uncertain how best to get the functionality I'm looking to create.

Right now I have an **index.html** with a login function (as seen in the **views.py** below) where the `render_to_response` that brings me to **portal/index.html**. However, as **urls.py** (see below) dictates, the url in the url bar of my browser is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/`. This means that refreshing the page forces the form to go again.

How do I get that url (once logged in) to look like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` or, if that's not feasible, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/portal/` - this is because I think it's clumsy that every time you reload the page once logged in, it forces the browser to open the prompt *Are you sure you want to send a form again?*.

Thank you so much for helping a Django newbie!

**views.py**

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
def login_user(request):
    #inactive_image_url = ""
    #invalid_credentials_url = ""
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)            
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
                return render_to_response('ucproject/portal/index.html', 
                        {'state':state, 'username':username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:
                #state_img = inactive_image_url
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact UC admin."
        else:
            #state_img = invalid_credentials_url
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
    return render_to_response('ucproject/index.html', 
            {'state': state,
             #'state_img': state_img,
             'username': username
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def portal(request):
    username = 'username'
    return render_to_response('ucproject/portal/index.html', 
            {'state': state,'username': username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**urls.py**

```
# Login / logout.
url(r'^registration/$', 'portal.views.registration'),
url(r'^login/$', 'portal.views.login_user'),
url(r'^portal/$', 'portal.views.portal'),
url(r'^portal/index.html$', 'portal.views.portal'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the HttpResponse here with a redirect:

```
if user.is_active:
    login(request, user)            
    state = "You're successfully logged in!"
    return render_to_response('ucproject/portal/index.html', 
           {'state':state, 'username':username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Instead, you want to use a name in urls.py to disambiguate:

```
urls.py
url(r'^portal/$', 'portal.views.portal', name='home'),
url(r'^portal/index.html$', 'portal.views.portal', name='home_index'),
```

then use something like this in your view:

```
if user.is_active:
    login(request, user)
    return redirect('home')
```

`redirect` is a shortcut function, but you could also create and return an `HttpResponseRedirect` object.  Usually there's no point in doing that.

Comment: +1 for using `redirect` instead of `HttpResponseRedirect`. Of course OP can try to do `return redirect('/')` to go back to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Comment: I do really like this answer, and I'm about to implement it and fiddle with it.

Comment: My only question about the redirect() is that I need to pass along the username variable along, and I'm not finding an easy way of doing it. Any tips?

Comment: Are you using the default Django auth?  If so, get the username in your portals.views.portal view from request.user.  If not, you probably want to put it into the session.